# Laravel 5: Database doesn't save through dropdown

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to save some data through dropdownlist .. after loading the page, database also fetched with the dropdown but it doesn't save after I clicked the save button. I think there is problem with Course migration table but I couldn't get it.
[Scenery is while taking courses student can take a class from the dropdown list.]

Here is my contoller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Course;
use App\TheClass;
use Redirect;

class courseController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $alldata=Course::all();
        return  view('course.index',compact('alldata'));
    }


    public function create()
    {
         $input=\App\TheClass::all();   
        return view('course.create',compact('input'));
    }


    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $input = $request->all();
        Course::create($input);
        return redirect('course');
    }
}
```

Here is my view page:

```
<html>
    <head> 
        <title> Create Course </title>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container" >
            <h3> Create course </h3>
        {!! Form::open(array('route' => 'course.store','class'=>'form-horizontal'))  !!}
        {!! Form::token(); !!}
            <?php echo csrf_field(); ?>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Course Code</label>
                <input type="text" name="course_code" class="form-control"  placeholder="Code">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Course Title</label>
                <input type="text" name="course_title" class="form-control"  placeholder="Title">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Course Credit</label>
                <input type="text" name="course_credit" class="form-control"  placeholder="Credit">
            </div>
   <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Class</label>
            <select class="form-control input-sm" name="class_id" >
            @foreach($input as $row)
            <option value="{{$row->class_id}}">{{$row->class_name}}</option>

            @endforeach
            </select>
          </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Course Table Migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCourseTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('courses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('course_id');
            $table->string('course_code',10);
             $table->string('course_title',50);
             $table->string('course_credit');
            $table->integer('class_id')->unsigned(); 
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('class_id')->references('id')->on('classes');  
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('courses');
    }
}
```

The Class table Migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateClassTable extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('classes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('class_name',10);            
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }


    public function down()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Add the content of your course model in your question and tell us what kind of error you are getting now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `{{$row->class_id}}` to `{{$row->id}}`

Because your classes table does not have **class_id** column.

Answer (score 0):

- First of all you need to add `$fillable` to your model as `create`
  method uses [Mass Assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#mass-assignment).
- Secondly I dont see any `category` field in migrations. Your `select`
  has name `category` so in database also should be `category` field.

Basically here you need to use [One To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

P.S. Don't have enough points for comments so answered.

Comment: 1. First of all i have already use $fillable in my model.
2. that was copy+paste mistake.. that's not that much effective.

I'm still facing the same problem. 
Thanks for your comment BTW!

Comment: But I still cant see `category` field in the migrations. What the tables structure actually looks like?